# OpenCL program freezes when using GPU

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu

My program doesn't work both using CPU and GPU:

```
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
```

When using CPU I receive this message:

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FEE30E8F90 (amdocl64.dll) in
>   Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. If there is a handler for this exception, the
>   program may be safely continued.

The problem appears while executing this command:

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, Cmobj, CL_TRUE, 0,
K*L*sizeof(float), C, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

When using GPU program freezes when executing this command:

```
ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Is there problem with memory? Or something else?
I use Visual Studio 2012, AMD Radeon HD 6470M, AMD APP SDK 2.9-1

Comment: Given that you're getting a memory access violation error code (0xC0000005), something common to both implementations is null when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

How did you initialize `device_id` and `ret_num_devices`?

Normally, you need to call `clGetDeviceIDs` twice: first get the number of available devices, then allocate memory for the device IDs, then call it again to fill that memory, like this:

```
cl_uint       numDevices = 0;
cl_device_id  *devices;
status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &numDevices);    
if (numDevices > 0)
{
    devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
    status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, numDevices, devices, NULL);
}
else
{
  // error: no device available: exit or fall back to CPU ...      
}

// use any of the devices[0 .. numDevices-1]
// after compiling/loading the kernel, you can free(devices)
```

Some of the examples that come with the APP SDK also show this pattern, samples/opencl/cl/app/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cpp for example. Maybe you just use one of the examples and adapt it to your needs?

Comment: Yes, I just adapted example code (HelloWorld.cpp) for my need. 
So in fact I initialize `device_id` and `ret_num_devices` this way:

`cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_int ret;
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);`

And that's it, there is no twice call of `clGetDeviceIDs` in my code.

Comment: Do you check what `ret` and `ret_num_devices` are? Also for all the other OpenCL initialization calls, do you check the return codes?

Comment: I checked it and `ret` is always stays zero, `ret_num_devices` stays 1. I replaced my code with yours, my program works normally, but `clBuildProgram` is really slow. Its execution takes about 5 minutes. Maybe it was slow before, I just didn't noticed it... I don't think this should be like that. Is that normal for this function?

Comment: Agreed; I'm thinking the platform isn't AMD or Intel, so there is no CPU device. What is the value of `ret` from your first call?